# Package 'libmono2.0-cil' has no installation candidate

Tags: mono, monodevelop

```
sudo apt-get install libmono2.0-cil
```

I tried apt-get update and upgrade

Is there a way to download this package?

Comment: It's only available in [12.04 and 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmono2.0). Which version are you using?

Comment: May I suggest you edit your question and explain what is the intended purpose for installing it? Chances are you may be following some outdated guide. Avoid the X-Y problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04 64bit i need it to run this game server on this tutorial https://unturned.wiki/info/tutorials/tutorial-dedicated-server/

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the new packages recommended by Ubuntu's package manager. I was able to get an unturned server working by simply following the suggestions the package manager produced. When you try to install the libmono2.0-cil package (as directed by the unturned setup instructions), Ubuntu will display this message:

`Package libmono2.0-cil is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mono-reference-assemblies-2.0 mono-devel libmono-cil-dev`

I just followed the suggestion and installed the recommended packages. Do a `sudo apt-get install mono-reference-assemblies-2.0 mono-devel libmono-cil-dev`.